# Regex look-behind issue

Tags: python, regex

I've seen in other posts that this is the proper way of solving the not fixed width pattern issue when doing `(?<!X|Y|Z)`, but is not working for me.

im trying the following

```
re.search(r'\b(?:(?<!Yummy)|(?<!Xoo))\bfoo\b', "Yummy foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => True
re.search(r'\b(?:(?<!Yummy)|(?<!Xoo))\bfoo\b', "Xoo foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => True
re.search(r'\b(?:(?<!Yummy)|(?<!Xoo))\bfoo\b', "other Yummy  foo someone", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => True
```

It always returns True, when it should return False. Now, if I remove the or |, it works fine.

```
re.search(r'\b(?:(?<!Yummy))\bfoo\b', "Yummy foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => False
re.search(r'\b(?<!Yummy)\bfoo\b', "Yummy foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => False
re.search(r'\b(?<!Yummy)\bfoo\b', " Yummy  foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => False
re.search(r'\b(?<!Yummy)\bfoo\b', "other Yummy foo someone", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => False
re.search(r'\b(?<!Yummy)\bfoo\b', "foo someone", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => True
re.search(r'\b(?<!Yummy)\bfoo\b', "foo", flags=re.UNICODE) is not None => True
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of updating the post, why don't you ask it in a separate question. **Decide what you want to ask?** because **there is no meaning of any answer that is answered based on your last edit.**

Comment: yeas, sorry as i tried your suggestions i realized is much more complex or restricted question. i will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an alternation since lookbehinds are zero width assertions, you can write this:

```
re.search(r'\b(?<!\bYum)(?<!\bXooop)\s+foo\b', "Yum foo", flags=re.UNICODE)
            ^ ^         ^
            | |         |
            +-+---------+---These three assertions are tested at the same
                            position (i.e. immediatly before the \s+ match.
                            You can put them in any order you want, they are
                            only checks and don't eat characters.
```

Comment: can I combine both `(?<!Yum)` and `(?<!Xoo)` into `(?<!(Yum|Xoo)`?

Comment: It's allowed with PHP, but not with python. You can make tests here: https://pythex.org/

Comment: I don't have any such knowledge but it's working as per the url that you shared me. I tested with `\b(?<!Yummy)(?<!Xoo)\s+foo\b` as well. can you share me some example in that case it's not working.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sounds to me OP needs to import the regex module since OP has changed the question multiple times and the strings are variable width it seems, and the regex module allows variable width.

Comment: @Braj: Yes, because "Yum" and "Xoo" have each one three letters, but if you change "Xoo" to "Xooo", it's no more allowed.

Comment: @hwnd: It's a possibility, but since the OP looks for exact words and not for a subpattern like `a\w+b`, the variable length is not needed, he only need to write several lookbehind in a single file.